# using regex in if-else

Tags: regex, bash

I know this must have been covered here...but i m a new to regex.

I am trying to use a regex in if-else statement
but not getting to correct value.

I am trying to match an entered string to a regex `[a-z][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9]`

here is the code :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please Enter the string starting with an 'ALPHABET' and the other characters can be 'ALPHA NUMERIC'"
read str

if ("$str" == '[a-z][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9]');
then
echo "Correct"
else 
echo "Incorrect"
fi
```

whatever value i give i am getting Incorrect...

Comment: what shell do you use? This is probably not `bash` syntax...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seriously doubt this is valid bash syntax.

First of all, `bash` uses the `=~` operator.

But this won't solve your problem entirely. An `if` clause in `bash` is placed between **square brackets** and `bash` is very sensitive to spaces as well. A working program would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please Enter the string starting with an 'ALPHABET' and the other characters can be 'ALPHA NUMERIC'"
read str

if [[ $str =~ ^[a-z][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9]$ ]];
then
    echo "Correct";
else 
    echo "Incorrect";
fi
```

Note that the regex is not a string. Furthermore the code modified the regex with `^` in the front and `$` at the end. This forces `bash` to match the **entire string**.

---

About your regex: it doesn't match the description in your program. You ask for a string starting with `[A-Za-z]` and then, optionally, one or more alphanum characters. A correct regex for this is:

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*
```

The asterisk means zero, one or more repetitions of the last character.

Comment: Thanks for explanation...I am new to scripting 
your trick worked...

its working fine now

#!/bin/bash

echo "Please Enter the string starting with an 'ALPHABET' and the other characters can be 'ALPHA NUMERIC'"
read str

if [[ $str =~ ^[A-z][A-z0-9]{2,7}$ ]]
then
echo "Correct"
else
echo "Incorrect"
fi

Answer (score 2):

To match regular expressions in bash, you need to use the `=~` operator.

```
if [[ $str =~ ^[a-z][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9]$ ]];
then
    echo "Correct";
else 
    echo "Incorrect";
fi
```